# SD card drivers for beaglebone during boot

Tags: embedded-linux, device-driver

I bought a Beaglebone(white) board a long time back, but wasn't able to work in that.

I am learning Embedded Linux device driver development using that.

I have questions please help me if you know:

- How is the SD card detected during the boot time?
- Where the device drivers will be loaded?

Basically I wanted to know if the SD card driver in the embedded system belongs to platform drivers or block drivers?

Comment: You really should do some research before posting here, check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The device drivers won't be loaded until you boot into Linux. Do you have U-Boot on your beagle? If so, use the help command to see what is available to you.